# RXJava stop observable inside flatmap

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I made a geotagged social report application to report broken streets on Android. It requires location data to post a report. Either from photo's Exif, Gps sensor or set it manually from MapsPickerActivity.

I managed to make the location request using [RxLocation](https://github.com/patloew/RxLocation) library. There's a button that's being made enabled when the app is still getting the location from Gps. Since getting a location data from Gps might take a while, I let the user to just set a location manually at the same time. I want to stop the getGpsLocationObservable if the user pressed the button. If I don't stop the getGpsLocationObservable, I'm afraid the process would still be running and come after setting a custom location. That would be annoying.
How could I achieve that?

Here's snippets of the simplified code

Main disposable :

```java
Disposable myDisposable = imageProcessingObservable()
    .compose(getExifLocationTransformer()) //custom location button enabled here 
    .filter(isLocationSet -> isLocationSet)
    .flatmap(x->getGpsLocationObservable());
```

RxLocation getGpsLocationObservable :

```java
private Observable<String> getGpsLocationObservable(){
    locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
        .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
        .setNumUpdates(1)
        .setInterval(3000);
    rxLocation = new RxLocation(PostActivity.this);
    rxLocation.setDefaultTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    return rxLocation.settings()
        .checkAndHandleResolution(locationRequest)
        .flatMapObservable(isActivated->{
            if (isActivated) {
                return locationSettingsActivatedObservable();
            }
            else locationNotFoundObservable();
        });
}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
private Observable<String> locationSettingsActivatedObservable(){
    return rxLocation.location().updates(locationRequest)
        .map(location -> {
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());
            String street = getStreetName(latLng);
            return street;
        })
        .doOnNext(street->{
            updateUI(street);
        });
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: The code is very long and ugly. I chained the whole process on an observable from processing the picture after taking it from gallery/camera (compress, rotate, saving to file provider), then transform it into exif reader to get the location data. If failed/not found proceed to flatmap the observable into getLocationWithGps. I enable the pick custom location button on exifreader complete/error . But alright, I'll try to embed the code.

Comment: Have a look at `takeUntil` and use a button's click event as a source to it.

Comment: @akarnokd yeah, that's exactly what I'm looking for. I'm actually quite new to RxJava (just begin to learn it about 2 weeks ago), I don't even bother reading every single operator documentation. Get totally overwhelmed learning the basic concept of Rx programming in the first week. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's a great use case for *.amb()* operator which only takes output of the observable which started emitting first and ignores all others. See http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#amb-rx.Observable-rx.Observable-

Comment: I ended up creating a PublisherSubject that sent true value whenever the button is pressed. Then put it in takeUntil operator on getGpsLocationObservable. As I see it fit better, or rather simpler for my current use case. Thanks anyway